# Network connection monitor

Tags: performance, vba, networking, winapi, status-monitoring

I was recently in need of a class that checks if a computer has a valid internet connection, so I wrote one; however, I feel that there is a better way to do so and I just don't have the knowledge myself. The object I choose to wrap is the [Win32_NeworkAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter), which unfortunately forces me to use "stringly" comparisons to determine the `NetconnectionID` (see `DetermineConnectionStatus` procedure below).

I am looking for suggestions on efficiency, possible caveats to what I am using currently, and anything else anyone comes up with.

**NetworkConnectionMonitor (Class):**

```
Option Explicit

Private Const NULL_VALUE As String = "null"

Private Const WIFI_CONNECTION_ID As String = "Wi-Fi"
Private Const ETHERNET_V1_CONNECTION_ID As String = "Ethernet"
Private Const ETHERNET_V2_CONNECTION_ID As String = "Ethernet 2"
Private Const BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION_ID As String = "Bluetooth Network Connection"
Private Const LAN_CONNECTION_ID As String = "Local Area Connection"

Private Type TNetworkConnectionMonitor
    HasWiFi As Boolean
    HasEthernetV1 As Boolean
    HasEthernetV2 As Boolean
    HasBluetooth As Boolean
    HasLocalAreaConnection As Boolean
    ConnectedToInternet As Boolean
End Type

Private Enum NetworkConnectionStatusEnum
    Disconnected
    Connecting
    Connected
    Disconnecting
    HardwareNotPresent
    HardwareDisabled
    HardwareMalfunction
    MediaDisconnected
    Authenticating
    AuthenticationSucceeded
    AuthenticationFailed
    InvalidAddress
    CredentialsRequired
End Enum

Private this As TNetworkConnectionMonitor

Public Property Get HasWiFi()
    HasWiFi = this.HasWiFi
End Property

Public Property Get HasEthernetV1()
    HasEthernetV1 = this.HasEthernetV1
End Property

Public Property Get HasEthernetV2()
    HasEthernetV2 = this.HasEthernetV2
End Property

Public Property Get HasBluetooth()
    HasBluetooth = this.HasBluetooth
End Property

Public Property Get HasLocalAreaConnection()
    HasLocalAreaConnection = this.HasLocalAreaConnection
End Property

Public Property Get ConnectedToInternet()
    ConnectedToInternet = this.ConnectedToInternet
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    DetermineConnectionStatus
End Sub

Private Sub DetermineConnectionStatus()

    Dim WinMgmtInsrumentation As Object, WinNtwkAdapter As Object, Instance As Object

    Set WinMgmtInsrumentation = GetObject("WINMGMTS:\\.\ROOT\cimv2")

    Set WinNtwkAdapter = WinMgmtInsrumentation.InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapter")

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    For Each Instance In WinNtwkAdapter
        If Instance.NetconnectionID <> NULL_VALUE Then

            Select Case Instance.NetconnectionID
                'conduct bit wise comparisons
                Case WIFI_CONNECTION_ID
                    If (Instance.NetConnectionStatus And _
                        NetworkConnectionStatusEnum.Connected) Then this.HasWiFi = True

                Case ETHERNET_V1_CONNECTION_ID
                    If (Instance.NetConnectionStatus And _
                        NetworkConnectionStatusEnum.Connected) Then this.HasEthernetV1 = True

                Case ETHERNET_V2_CONNECTION_ID
                    If (Instance.NetConnectionStatus And _
                        NetworkConnectionStatusEnum.Connected) Then this.HasEthernetV2 = True

                Case BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION_ID
                    If (Instance.NetConnectionStatus And _
                        NetworkConnectionStatusEnum.Connected) Then this.HasBluetooth = True

                Case LAN_CONNECTION_ID
                    If (Instance.NetConnectionStatus And _
                        NetworkConnectionStatusEnum.Connected) Then this.HasLocalAreaConnection = True

            End Select

        End If
    Next

    'If None of these are true then not connected to the internet
    this.ConnectedToInternet = (this.HasEthernetV2 Or this.HasWiFi Or this.HasEthernetV1)

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub


Public Function IsConnectedToHost(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal PingCount As Integer, _
                                  Optional ByVal PingTimeOut As Long = 550)

    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        IsConnectedToHost = (.Run("%comspec% /c ping.exe -n " & PingCount & _
                                 " -w " & PingTimeOut & " " & HostName & _
                                 " | find ""TTL="" > nul 2>&1", 0, True) = 0)
    End With

End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Private Sub TestConnections()

    Dim NetworkStatus As NetworkConnectionMonitor

        Set NetworkStatus = New NetworkConnectionMonitor

        If Not NetworkStatus.ConnectedToInternet Then MsgBox "You Are not Connected to the internet"

        If Not NetworkStatus.IsConnectedToHost("some.hostdomanin.com", 2) Then MsgBox "You Are not Connected to the host"

End Sub
```